# Does the fire damage of a bow still work with lightning arrow?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, weapons, damage, ranger

My ranger has a bow I used the 'opal of the ild rune' on. It gives my bow an extra 1d6 fire damage.

The lightning arrow spell states that it replaces the normal damage of the weapon (the arrow in this case). But, the fire damage is added by the bow, not the arrow.

So, does the fire damage stay, because it is part of the bow, not the arrow? Or does the lightning arrow replace all damage, including the extra damage from the bow?

Comment: What source are you using for 'Opal of the Ild Rune' and which part?  I looked in the UA pdf for Rune Magic and I don't see a +1d6 fire property.

Comment: You can use the rune to transfer the power of it to a weapon to give the weapon a +1d6 fire damage. That destroys the opal.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**It replaces.**

Lightning Arrow replaces the normal damage of the weapon used in the ranged weapon attack, which, strictly speaking, is the bow. As one might notice when attempting to determine the normal damage of any ranged weapon attack, ammunition is not a weapon itself and has no damage profile (excepting magical ammunition and its attendant rules). The fire damage, as a property of the bow and thus a component of it's normal damage, is thereby replaced.